# Base url is localhost for images in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i changed my site URL in server but logo image read from `localhost://`. how can i change URL for logo image.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to you wp-config.php just change

> define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' ); define( 'WP_SITEURL',
> 'http://example.com' );

otherwise follow suggestion from this link
[Wordpress doc](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/)

Comment: i changed it but does not work . i changed URL from database and settings ->general but does not work . logo image read from localhost:// URL .